# How to write a function to remove comments from a .m source file preserving formatting such as line wrapping reasonably?

Tags: string-manipulation, text, comment

How to write a function to remove comments from a .m source file preserving formatting such as line wrapping reasonably?

This means if I have

```
foo;
(* comment 1 *)
bar[
    baz (* comment 2 *)
    (* comment 3 *)
];
```

I'd ideally end up getting

```
foo;
bar[
    baz
];
```

Comment: Use another tool.There are Legion better suited to the job. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative "first principle" approach, which does not use string patterns as a main tool, but instead makes use of the fact that comments have a simple structure and can only be escaped when they appear inside strings. Therefore, we can write a very simple parser which only parses strings and comments. Here is the tokenizer:

```
ClearAll[expr, parse, string, comments,tokenize, $commentPattern, $stringPattern];

tokenize[s_String] := StringSplit[s, t : "\\\"" | "\"" | "(*" | "*)" :> t];
```

Here are auxiliary patterns we will need:

```
$stringPattern = 
   PatternSequence["\"", middle___, "\""] /; ! MemberQ[{middle}, "\""];

$commentPattern = 
   PatternSequence["(*", middle___, "*)"] /; 
      Count[{middle}, "(*"] == Count[{middle}, "*)"];
```

Here is the parser:

```
parse[left___, s : $stringPattern, right___] :=
   expr[parse[left], string[s], parse[right]];

parse[left___, c : $commentPattern, right___] :=
   expr[parse[left], comments[c], parse[right]];

parse[{tokens___}] := parse[tokens];
parse[tokens___] := expr[tokens];
```

The heads `expr`, `string` and `comments` are inert heads.

Finally, here is the function to remove comments from a string of code:

```
ClearAll[removeComments];
removeComments[s_String] :=
  StringJoin[
    DeleteCases[parse[tokenize@s], _comments, Infinity] /. 
      expr | string -> Sequence
  ]
```

Applying this to the initial string of code `str` as `removeComments[str]` returns the expected answer.

This parser won't be particularly fast. The reason I like this approach is that it does not rely on some external things such as specific forms of `Import`, so it will only be wrong if the principles are wrong (e.g. I missed some other forms where comments can be escaped, etc), but I consider string manipulations rather fragile for parsing purposes generally. Interestingly, this seems to be one of the simplest problems I know of which illustrates that regexps [are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to parse code representing recursive (nested) expressions / statements.

Comment: Parsing sure is better than pattern matching. Is it possible to handle escaped citation marks, for instance: `"a=\"string1\\\"(* Not a comment *)\";\n(* Comment *)\nb=\"string2\";"`

Comment: @ssch Yes, sure. I only had to slightly modify the tokenizer, see in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** Combining mine and Rolfs answer gives a pretty robust way:

```
str="foo;
(* bar *)
s=\"(*\"
bar[
    baz (* comment 2 *)
    (* comment 3 
       (* With nested (* comment 4 *) *)
    *)
];"; (* Import["t.m","Text"]; *)

(* Change to: Import["t.m",... *)
comments = ImportString[str, {"Package", "Comments"}];
rule = Flatten[{
      StartOfLine ~~ " " ... ~~ "(*" ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ # ~~ 
        Whitespace ... ~~ "*)\n" -> "",
      "(*" ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ # ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ "*)" -> ""
      } & /@ comments];
StringReplace[str, rule]

(* out:
foo;
s="(*"
bar[
    baz 
];
*)
```

It extracts the specific comments and looks for a string like `"(* That comment *)"` Ignoring any whitespace between `(*` and the comment since that is stripped by `Import["t.m", {"Package", "Comments"}]`.

*end of update*

I look for comment-only lines separately to get rid of the extra spacing and newline. Other than that it's just simple [string patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StringPatterns.html).

Caution: Since this is just simple pattern matching there's bound to be some edge cases where it doesn't work. For instance if the .m has `s="(*"` somewhere this will break for sure

```
str = "foo;
  (* comment 1 *)
  bar[
      baz (* comment 2 *)
      (* comment 3 *)
  ];";
StringReplace[str,
 {
  StartOfLine ~~ " " ... ~~ "(*" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "*)\n" -> "",
  "(*" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "*)" -> ""
  }]
(* out:
"foo;
bar[
    baz 
];"
*)
```

Comment: +1 nice way to look for the comment patterns - that should make it easier to rule out the last obstacle: it still fails when you have `s=\"(* comment 2 *)\"` in the code where the comment shouldn't be removed because it's in a string...

Comment: @Jens Good catch, I can't figure out any sane way to resolve that within the limitations of pattern matching :)

Answer (score 3):

As observed by ssh, the simple string replacements will not work if comment delimiters are contained as parts of string arguments in your source. For example, this could be a file you're looking at:

```
txt = Import["t.m", "Text"]
```

with the content:

```
foo["(* Don't *) erase!
"];
(* comment 1 *)
bar[
    baz (* comment 2 *)
    (* comment 3 *)
];
```

Then a very simple way to get rid of the comments is this:

```
ToExpression[txt, StandardForm, HoldForm]
```

> `foo[(* Don't *) erase!`
>
> `];bar[baz];`

Granted, this doesn't preserve the line breaks and indentation, but it's quick and foolproof (or `foo`proof ?).

**Edit**

Here is a slightly improved version that preserves line breaks:

```
StringJoin[Riffle[DeleteCases[
   StringSplit[
    ToString[
     With[{a = StringReplace[txt, "\n" :> "$newlinecharacter;"]},
          ToExpression[a, StandardForm, HoldForm]
          ]], "$newlinecharacter;"], " "], "\n"]]
```

**Edit 2**

The outputs above look as if they don't have the quotation marks of the string - but they are there, you just have to do

```
Export["t2.m", %]
```

on the result. Or you can copy the output above and paste it into an input cell. The `"` will show up then.

Comment: `ToString` is being a bit of an annoyance breaking `"`: `ToString[HoldForm[s="1+1"]] // FullForm` gives "s = 1 + 1"

Comment: @ssh It does look ugly, but in my edit 2 I mention that sometimes the export is OK (not for your example unfortunately). Anyway, my solution doesn't preserve the format completely, so you're right that I need an alternative to `ToString`...

Comment: @ssch try: `ToString[HoldForm[s = "1+1"], InputForm] // FullForm`

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do this with string patterns. 
So t.m is

```
foo;
(* comment 1 *)
bar[
    baz (* comment 2 *)
    (* comment 3 *)
];
```

Then definining a file fix2 with

```
Export["t2.m",
StringReplace[
        StringReplace[Import["t.m","Text"] ,
                Thread[ Import["t.m",{"Package","Comments"}] ->""]],
        "(*"~~ Whitespace ~~"*)" -> ""],
"Text"]

FilePrint@"t2.m"
```

we get

```
In[1]:= <<fix2

foo;

bar[
    baz

];
```

Comment: If add `"*)"~~("\n"|"")~~s2__` it will also remove the newline as OP did in his example.

Comment: @jVincent you only want to remove the newline if the line is just a comment, perhaps: `{
 StartOfLine ~~ " " ... ~~ "(*" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "*)\n" -> "",
 "(*" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "*)" -> ""
 }`

Comment: What does `!!t.m` mean and do?

Comment: !! is like FilePrint, on Linux.

Comment: @ssch Nice, but it soon gets hard to read. I think using "Comments" of Import is simpler. But of course, your solution is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the cell expression corresponding to your example cell. It should not be too hard to find the expression programmatically, for example by giving it a cell tag and using Cells and NotebookRead. Anyway, let's work with this for the moment.

```
cell = Cell[BoxData[{
      RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"foo", ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
         RowBox[{"(*", 
            RowBox[{"comment", " ", "1"}], "*)"}]}], "\n", 
      RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"bar", "[", "baz", " ", 
            RowBox[{"(*", 
               RowBox[{"comment", " ", "2"}], "*)"}], 
         "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
            RowBox[{"(*", 
               RowBox[{"comment", " ", "3"}], "*)"}], "]"}], ";"}]}], 
   "Input"];
```

We can then simply do

```
DeleteCases[cell, RowBox[{"(*", ___, "*)"}], Infinity] // CellPrint
```

giving

```
(*the lines below are the contents of the cell printed by the code above*)

foo;

bar[baz 
  ];
```

I hope to play around with Leonids parser a great deal, I find such things extremely interesting. But I thought this would be a refreshing alternative.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is really not about .m files, unless you of course generate those .m files from notebooks. Anyway, as I know of no Q&A really dealing with preserving formatting and deleting comments or something similar I will keep it.

Comment: Related [Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26136/4330).