# Convert array from {{...}} to "[[...]]"

Tags: list-manipulation, export, string-manipulation

I have made this function:

```
conv01 = Map["["<>StringJoin@@Riffle[#,","]<>"]"&,Map[ToString,#,{2}],{0,1}]&
```

to convert:

```
list = {{1, 2, "test3"}, {3, 4, "test4"}}
```

to

```
"[[1, 2, \"test3\"], [3, 4, \"test4\"]]"
```

I know that I can do: `conv02 = StringReplace[ToString[#], {"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}] &` but it's not safe if I have `{` or `}` inside it.

I have tried:

```
conv03 = Map["[" <> ToString@Row[#, ","] <> "]" &, list, {0, 1}]
```

but it doesn't work and I don't understand why if this works:

```
"[" <> ToString@Row[{1, 2, 3, 4}, ","] <> "]"
```

Some clue on the last method? Some idea of simpler solution?

Comment: What's the purpose for making this change?

Comment: @bobthechemist I don't think the first method has a good performance. And code reader is clumsy.

Comment: Do you mean `{"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}]` rather than `{"{" -> "{", "}" -> "]"}]`?  Do I understand that your goal is to convert a *Mathematica* expression to a string, while replacing the list delimiters `{` and `}` with `[` and `]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes.!. Corrected. And the goal is that too. Tks

Comment: I presume `dados` also should be `list` in the `conv03` line?

Comment: shame on me... yes

Comment: hehehe... :-) --- okay, I think none of your functions are preserving quote characters for the original strings `"test3"` and `"test4"`; what do you intend?

Comment: Yes.. I need to preserve quotes for strings

Comment: So besides `{` and `}` characters that occur *within* an internal string you can replace all of these with `[` and `]`, correct?

Comment: Yes.. I need to use it in some HTML generated by WebMathematica. The java code from [this](http://handsontable.com/) free grid component uses this syntax.

Comment: Okay, one final question (I hope): would introducing spaces (as in `InputForm`) like: `[[1, 2, "test3"], [3, 4, "test4"]]` be OK or not?

Comment: No problem. It can have spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For working with jQuery/Javascript, you need to use JSON:

```
ExportString[{
  {1, 2, "Three"},
  {4, 5, "{Six}"}
  }, "JSON"]
```

Comment: Very interesting... sound good tks +1

Comment: Hm... no JSON in v7 but this may be the solution. :-)

Comment: Yes, to be clear about this: the plugin accepts JSON. JSON is the list equivalent of Javascript, so this is not a lucky coincident, it's simply the right format.

Comment: The object equivalent even, `ExportString[{"x"->{1,2,3}, "y" -> {"z"->41}}, "JSON"]` gives the javascript object definition: `"{\"x\" : [
 1, 
 2, 
 3
], 
\"y\" : {\"z\" : 41}}"`

Comment: I have made some test. and this is just a little bit slow, but very robust against wrong parse.

Answer (score 4):

How about removing heads from `FullForm`?

```
list = {{1, 2, "test3"}, {3, 4, "test4"}};
StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@list, "List[" -> "["]
```

> ```
>   "[[1, 2, \"test3\"], [3, 4, \"test4\"]]"
> ```

Comment: That's quite clever (+1) but it will also expand every subexpression to FullForm as well.

Comment: I would change `"List" -> ""` by `"List["->"["`, to avoid strings with List inside to be replaced. Tks +1

Comment: Thanks Murta, added! @Mr.W I am aware of it, but since the original expression seemed simple enough I assumed only atoms could appear in the lists.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments above this may suit you:

```
bracketFormat[expr_] :=
 StringReplace[
  ToString[expr, InputForm],
  {s : Shortest["\"" ~~ __ ~~ "\""] :> s, "{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}
 ]

list = {{1, 2, "test3"}, {3, 4, "test4", "trick{}"}};

bracketFormat[list]
```

> ```
> "[[1, 2, \"test3\"], [3, 4, \"test4\", \"trick{}\"]]"
> ```

Which will export as:

> ```
> [[1, 2, "test3"], [3, 4, "test4", "trick{}"]]
> ```

A robust version of this method would be based on Leonid's simple parser:
[How to write a function to remove comments from a .m source file preserving formatting such as line wrapping reasonably?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/how-to-write-a-function-to-remove-comments-from-a-m-source-file-preserving-form/17666#17666)

Comment: Interesting behavior of string replace for multiple replacement. The rule is not applied to parts already changed, so "{}" is preserved inside strings.

Comment: @Murta Correct, or at least that was my intention.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a unique identifier and strip it away at the end:

```
With[{s = StringJoin@RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 30]}, 
    StringReplace[ToString[list /. {x_String :> "\"" ~~ x ~~ "\"", List -> s}], s -> ""]
]
(* [[1, 2, "test3"], [3, 4, "test4"]] *)
```

This works because something of the form `"a"[0]` is valid (i.e. a function call on a string) and only the head `List` is matched; not `"List"` or `"{}"`.

Comment: How can I put quotes?

Comment: @Murta Change the replacement to `{x_String :> "\"" ~~ x ~~ "\"", List -> s}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a v10 function that simplifies this process dramatically: [`TextString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextString.html). It has several options for specifying how different constructs are formatted. In this case, you are looking for [`ListFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListFormat.html), e.g.

```
ListFormat -> {"[", ",", "]"}
```

Unfortunately, it does not have an option for changing a strings format, so we have to improvise. The [docs](http://wolfram.com/xid/0tztbhci-n4ot1c) use an `UpValue`

```
quoted /: TextString[quoted[str_]] := "\"" <> str <> "\"";
```

But, this requires you to know where the string is in your input to begin with, so I suggest adding another `UpValue` and modifying the first, e.g.

```
quoted /: TextString[quoted[str_String]] := "\"" <> str <> "\"";
quoted /: TextString[quoted[str_]] := TextString@str;
```

Then, you can do

```
TextString[MapAll[quoted, list], ListFormat -> {"[", ",", "]"}]
(* "[[1,2,\"test3\"],[3,4,\"test4\"]]" *)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, if the source object is a String?

```
ToExpression@"{{2,3,\"List[thiswouldbreaksomeothermethods] test{123}\"},{3,5,\"more [stuff]\"}}" /. List :> ("[" <> StringJoin[ToString /@ {##}~Riffle~","] <> "]" &)
```

or if you have the source object as a Mathematica List:

```
{{2,3,"List[thiswouldbreaksomeothermethods] test{123}"},{3,5,"more [stuff]"}} /. List :> ("[" <> StringJoin[ToString /@ {##}~Riffle~","] <> "]" &)
```

Output:

```
"[[2,3,List[thiswouldbreaksomeothermethods] test{123}],[3,5,more [stuff]]]"
```

It takes a string, ignores any bracket characters in it that are parts of string contents, makes a List of it, then creates the string you want out of it with square brackets.

FYI:

In Mathematica, `{...}` is shorthand for `List`, but `[...]` is not a complete entity, as it represents a body of parameters to a head while lacking the head itself. Closes thing there is to it is `Sequence[]`. Such that `{1,2,3}/.List->Sequence` results in `1,2,3` set of values, but this set would still not be accurately represented with `[1,2,3]`.

Asking Mathematica for `[1, 2, 3] // FullForm` generates an `Incomplete expression; more input is needed.` error.

Comment: This method is not sensitive like many others to the string contents since there's not a StringReplace, so `"List", "List["` and other types of strings are very valid in the contents. If you have the source as a List and don't need `ToExpression`, then anything at all goes, even Mathematica code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
list={{1,2,"123"},{1,2,"123"}};

Module[{$replace$},
    StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@Map[ $replace$@@#&,list,{0,1}],ToString@$replace$->""]
]
```

Comment: To be fair, I'll choose the answer with more upvotes.